# Reason behind a method defined to explicitly access model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just ran across this code while resolving some merge conflicts and am having a tough time understanding the justification for doing something like this.

Can anyone tell me if there is a good reason for having a method defined to access the model explicitly.

```
private
def message_class
  CustomerMessage
end

def lookup_message_class
  CustomerMessage
end
```

Hopefully i am just misunderstanding something, because this is done multiple times by a coworker.

Comment: The only sane answer to this question is: **Go ask your coworker**. It was seemingly done by somebody who doesn't understand that *all* objects have a `class` method already, but how on earth are we to know whether he had a better reason?

Comment: i was just hoping this was some convention I had never seen before

Answer (score 1):

No point of doing that.

If you want to change the class afterward, change it everywhere.

Comment: What does this have to do with *changing* a class? "Afterward" what?

Comment: that's the only reason I could've imagine why you would want to wrap a class in an instance method...